# Why does rerendering not effect counting with setTimeout?

Tags: reactjs

I have a component with controlled inputs. This component is also a parent for a Timer component. The Timer component counts down from 20 to 0 using setTimeout. Right now the child component rerenders on every key stroke (and therefore the state change) in a parent component.

```
const Timer = () => {
    const [secondsLeft, setSecondsLeft] = useState(20);

    if (secondsLeft) { 
        setTimeout(() => setSecondsLeft(secondsLeft - 1), 1000);   
    }

    const displayTime = '00:' + String(secondsLeft).padStart(2, '0');

    if (secondsLeft > 0) { 
        return <span>Time left {displayTime}</span>;   
    }
    
    return <span>You're out of time!</span>;
};
```

My question is why the countdown timer works properly and it's interval is always exacly 1 second no matter how fast I type in a parent input element. Why rerendering does not affect the setTimeout?

Comment: You never clear the timeout, so it still fires 1000ms after being set up.

Comment: but why clear it? The component updates, not being destroyed

Comment: If you want rerendering to affect the timing of `setTimeout`, you'll want to clear the timeout and create a new one on each rerender since there is no way to update an existing timeout. You can clear the timeout in a cleanup callback if you wrap your timeout setup in `useEffect`.

Comment: As far as I understand no matter how many times the component updates it still uses the timer that was created first. And it is never destroyed. But what abot other timner that are created on rerender? Why do they not affect anything?

Comment: Are you sure the component is rerendering when you type into the parent component?

Comment: because if you update 5 times in a second, you now have 5 timers that will call `setSecondsLeft(secondsLeft - 1)` for that second. Luckily only the first one triggers a rerender because the subsequent calls don't change the value. try using `setSecondsLeft(secondsLeft  => secondsLeft - 1)`

Comment: thank you! If you write this as a answer, I'll mark it as a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you update 5 times in a second, you now have 5 timers that will call `setSecondsLeft(secondsLeft - 1)` for that second. Luckily only the first one triggers a rerender because the subsequent calls don't change the value.

Try using:

```
setSecondsLeft(secondsLeft  => secondsLeft - 1)
```

<sub>Note: answer provided by [Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6567275/thomas) on comment section.</sub>

Comment: While this comment/answer solves the issue, it is inefficient. I would rather like to see an implementation of Henry Woody's suggestion with `useEffect` and timeout cleanup code in the useEffect's cleanup callback.